# awk to Count Sum and Unique improve command

Tags: awk

Would like to print based on 2nd column ,count of line items, sum of 3rd column and unique values of first column.Having around 100 InputTest files and not sorted ..
Am using below 3 commands to achieve the desired output , would like to know the simplest way ...

InputTest*.txt

```
abc,xx,5,sss
abc,yy,10,sss
def,xx,15,sss
def,yy,20,sss
abc,xx,5,sss
abc,yy,10,sss
def,xx,15,sss
def,yy,20,sss
ghi,zz,10,sss
```

Step#1:

```
cat InputTest*.txt | awk -F, '{key=$2;++a[key];b[key]=b[key]+$3} END {for(i in a) print i","a[i]","b[i]}'
```

Op#1

```
xx,4,40
yy,4,60
zz,1,10
```

Step#2

```
awk -F ',' '{print $1,$2}' InputTest*.txt | sort | uniq >Op_UniqTest2.txt
```

Op#2

```
abc xx
abc yy
def xx
def yy
ghi zz
```

Step#3

```
awk   '{print $2}' Op_UniqTest2.txt | sort | uniq -c
```

Op#3

```
 2 xx
 2 yy
 1 zz
```

Desired Output:

```
xx,4,40,2
yy,4,60,2
zz,1,10,1
```

Looking for suggestions !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }
{ ++lines[$2]; if (!seen[$2,$1]++) ++diff[$2]; count[$2]+=$3 }
END { for(i in lines) print i, lines[i], count[i], diff[i] }
```

- `lines` tracks the number of occurrences of each value in column 2
- `seen` records unique combinations of the second and first column, incrementing `diff[$2]` whenever a unique combination is found. The `++` after `seen[$2,$1]` means that the condition will only be true the first time the combination is found, as the value of seen[$2,$1] will be increased to 1 and !seen[$2,$1] will be false.
- `count` keeps a total of the third column

```
$ awk -f avn.awk file
xx,4,40,2
yy,4,60,2
zz,1,10,1
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }
{ keys[$2]++; sum[$2]+=$3 } !seen[$1,$2]++ { count[$2]++ }
END   { for(key in keys) print key, keys[key], sum[key], count[key] }
' file
xx,4,40,2
yy,4,60,2
zz,1,10,1
```

Set the input and output field separator to `,` in `BEGIN` block. We use arrays `keys` to identify and count keys. `sum` array keeps the sum for each keys. `count` allows us to keep track of unique column1 for each of column2 values.